# XCode not showing leaks in C++ program

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode-instruments

I wrote the following piece of code as an xcode command line tool in c++

```
int * num = new int[100];

num[4] = 5;
num = NULL;

cout << "leaked" << endl;

string c; cin >> c;

return 0;
```

However, when profiling using Instruments with the Leaks template, it does not show any memory leaks, although there should clearly be one while it is waiting for input.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile for profiling, the compiler does optimizations.  One of those optimizations is dead-store optimization:

```
num = NULL; // The optimizer deleted this operation
```

Normally, why would you care if `num` actually equals `NULL`?  Since you never read the value of `num`, you have no way of knowing if the compiler actually stored `NULL` there without looking at the assembly output.  So the compiler doesn't bother actually writing `NULL` to that location.

### But wait, there's more

I did a test:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int *num = new int[100];
    num[4] = 5;
    num = NULL;
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly (prologue and epilogue omitted for brevity):

```
movl    $1, %edi
callq   _sleep
xorl    %eax, %eax
```

Wait a darn minute, what happened to `new int[100]` and `num[4] = 5`?

The entire allocation got optimized out, because the compiler figured out a way to get the same result without allocating anything.  Compilers are amazing, aren't they?

Comment: So to avoid this I should read from `num` after I assign it as `NULL`?

Comment: @user2612743: That might be enough to keep the variable live.  Although the lesson here is that you shouldn't trust the results you get from toy programs :-)